# How to find the files that are created in the last hour in unix

Tags: unix, find

How to find the files that are created in the last hour in unix

Answer (score 258):

If the dir to search is `srch_dir` then either

```bash
$ find srch_dir -cmin -60 # change time
```

or

```bash
$ find srch_dir -mmin -60 # modification time
```

or

```bash
$ find srch_dir -amin -60 # access time
```

shows files whose metadata has been changed (`ctime`), the file contents itself have been modified (`mtime`), or accessed (`atime`) in the last hour, respectively.

`ctime` is non-unintuitive and warrants further explanation:

> [`ctime`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-timestamps-mtime-ctime-and-atime-in-linux/):
> Unlike `mtime`, which is only related to the contents inside a file, changed timestamp indicates the last time some metadata of a file was changed. `ctime` refers to the last time when a file’s metadata.
> For example, if permission settings of a file were modified, `ctime` will indicate it.

Comment: This is great and all, but these flags don't exist on Solaris `find` that I'm using. OP said Unix and I think these are Linux only.

Comment: The trick is to use **negative** time values! It's not so obvious in the man page.

Comment: @jiggy [Ayush's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5242560/27358) gives a hack (based on `-newer`) that should work on Solaris.

Comment: -cmin is NOT creation time but change time! just deleted my .config dir cause on the test run it wasn't changed withhin the last X minutes and when I did rm it was.... so maybe edit this...!

Comment: I still think the first example comment needs a revision.  "change time" is the file status, not the file data

Comment: the change in meta data is what states in ctime

Comment: If I use these together, are they "OR'd"?

find . -path "*MORL*" -name "*.TXT" -cmin -1440 -mmin -1440 -amin 1440

Comment: @KCBaltz I gotchu. Just wasted about 6 hours on that myself before divining what it was.

Answer (score 25):

UNIX filesystems (generally) don't store creation times.  Instead, there are only access time, (data) modification time, and (inode) change time.

That being said, `find` has `-atime` `-mtime` `-ctime` predicates:

```
$ man 1 find
...
-ctime  n
        The primary shall evaluate as true if the time of last change of
        file status information subtracted from the initialization time,
        divided by 86400 (with any remainder discarded), is n.
...
```

Thus `find -ctime 0` finds everything for which the inode has changed (e.g. includes file creation, but also counts link count and permissions and filesize change) less than an hour ago.

Comment: 86400 seconds is a *day*, not an hour.  Thus the argument to `-ctime` etc is in units of _days_ rather than hours.

Answer (score 11):

check out [this link](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/13934-how-list-files-created-last-2-hrs.html) and then help yourself out.

the basic code is

```
#create a temp. file
echo "hi " >  t.tmp
# set the file time to 2 hours ago
touch -t 200405121120  t.tmp 
# then check for files
find /admin//dump -type f  -newer t.tmp -print -exec ls -lt {} \; | pg
```

Comment: Thanks, however this will only search for t.tmp. What if I want to find all the files created in the last hour.

Comment: Ankur : it will create a temporary file t.tmp and set its creation time to 2 hours ago...after that it will search in present directory all files which were created after t.tmp i.e in last 2 hours..

Comment: cool!! Though the first command is not necessary. `touch` creates the file if it does not exists already.

Answer (score 7):

`find ./ -cTime -1 -type f`

OR

`find ./ -cmin -60 -type f`

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo find / -Bmin 60
```

From the `man` page:

> -Bmin n
>
> True if the difference between the time of a file's inode creation and
>   the time `find` was started, rounded up to the next full minute, is n
>   minutes.

Obviously, you may want to set up a bit differently, but this primary seems the best solution for searching for any file created in the last *N* minutes.

Comment: `find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0` does not have a `-B` predicate

Answer (score -2):

Check out this [link](https://www.usessionbuddy.com/post/Unix-Find-Command-Cheatsheet-And-Usage/) for more details.

To find files which are created in last one hour in current directory, you can use -amin

find . -amin -60 -type f

This will find files which are created with in last 1 hour.

Comment: -amin gives you the latest access time, which by some file systems isn't even updated. So cmin and mmin are the options to use.