# Ksh command to find files modified during last hour

Tags: shell, scripting, solaris, ksh

Can you please tell me most efficient command which can be used to find files modified in a directory in last hour ( more precisely last 60 minutes).

Or

If its not good approach then please tell me how can I compare current time with the timestamp of file creation/modifition

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the files that are created in the last hour in unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242501/how-to-find-the-files-that-are-created-in-the-last-hour-in-unix) [has answers to created, modified, and accessed]

Comment: @ChrisJ Didn't notice and I could actually vote for it. But is it valid enough if the question is different? After all one search would not redirect the use to it quickly.

Comment: Hi, I had actually seen that thread before posting this new post, -mmin is not working in ksh for me. Don't know the reason & couldn't even find the manpage for it also.

Answer (score 0):

Use find's option `-newermt`:

```
find -newermt 'now -1 hour'
```

Or simply

```
find -newermt -1hour
```

Read more about the usage in find's [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

Another way for ksh:

```
BEFORE=$(date -d '-1 hour' '+%s'); find -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | while read -r TS FILE; do TS=${TS%.*}; [[ TS -ge BEFORE ]] && echo "$FILE"; done
```

Without using `-d`:

```
BEFORE=$(( $(date '+%s') - 3600 )); find -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | while read -r TS FILE; do TS=${TS%.*}; [[ TS -ge BEFORE ]] && echo "$FILE"; done
```

Comment: I tried executing updated command but even when tried with various combinations it doesn't help.

Comment: I also made an update after my notice. I hope you could compare that it's already the right one you're using.

Comment: Hi I am getting error for this one also..bash-3.00$ BEFORE=$(date -d '-1 hour' '+%s');echo $BEFORE
date: illegal option -- d
date: illegal option -- 1
date: illegal option --
date: illegal option -- h
date: illegal option -- o
date: illegal option -- r
usage:  date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff]

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your involvement in this issue but apparently these commands give errors which I posted above.

Comment: @user1809095 Any error? Also, make sure that it just doesn't wait for a file with a valid match but the processing still continues on many files.

Comment: I think the OP may be using ksh88, not ksh93, and is not on Linux, and/or does not have GNU date.

Answer (score 0):

This will work on most modern POSIX conforming systems, using ksh[nn] or bash.

```
filetime=$(perl -e'
    use POSIX qw(strftime);
    $now_string = strftime "%Y%m%d%H%M.%S", localtime(time - 3601);  
    print $now_string, "\n";' )
touch -t $filetime /tmp/dummy     # here for verification
ls -l /tmp/dummy
find . -newer /tmp/dummy -exec ls -l {} \;
```

the `ls - l` command is there to show you the "dummy", remove it after you check what the touch command does.

Answer (score 0):

Touch a file with timestamp of one hour old, and use find's option -newer.
The touch hour can be calculated with a timezone trick (example for GMT):

```
echo "$(TZ=GMT+1 date +%Y-%m-%d)"
```

So you do something like

```
HOUROLDFILE=/tmp/hourold.tmp
touch -t "$(TZ=GMT+1 date '+%y%m%d%H%M')" ${HOUROLDFILE}
find a_directory -newer ${HOUROLDFILE}
rm ${HOUROLDFILE}
```