# how can I find all the file which created after some time, in a given directory?

Tags: macos, shell, find

I google the [find doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/find.1.html),and wrote this

```
find . -type f -depth 1 -Btime 1
```

howerver ,I doesn`t work? how can I get this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-Btime 5` matches files that were created five days ago (where 4.1 is rounded up to 5 and 5.1 is rounded up to 6). If you meant files created between now and five days ago, use `-Btime -5`.

```
find . -type f -Btime -5 # five days ago or newer
find . -type f -Btime 5 # five days ago
find . -type f -Btime +5 # five days ago or older
find . -type f -Btime +5 -Btime -10 # between five days ago and ten days ago
```

Also `-maxdepth 1` or `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` is faster than `-depth 1`. `-depth 1` traverses all files under the directory tree.

The format that can be used with `-atime`, `-Btime`, `-ctime`, and `-mtime` is described under `-atime`:

```
-atime n[smhdw]
        If no units are specified, this primary evaluates to true if the difference
        between the file last access time and the time find was started, rounded up to
        the next full 24-hour period, is n 24-hour periods.

        If units are specified, this primary evaluates to true if the difference between
        the file last access time and the time find was started is exactly n units.  Pos-
        sible time units are as follows:

        s       second
        m       minute (60 seconds)
        h       hour (60 minutes)
        d       day (24 hours)
        w       week (7 days)

        Any number of units may be combined in one -atime argument, for example, ``-atime
        -1h30m''.  Units are probably only useful when used in conjunction with the + or
        - modifier.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post is similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671947/ksh-command-to-find-files-modified-during-last-hour). Anyhow you can have a command like this.

```
find -newerct 'now -1 hour'
```

Or

```
BEFORE=$(( $(date '+%s') - 3600 )) ## In seconds = 1 hour.
find -type f -printf '%C@ %p\n' | while read -r TS FILE; do TS=${TS%.*}; [[ TS -ge BEFORE ]] && echo "$FILE"; done
```

If you plan to base it from modification time, you can have this

```
find -newermt '-1 hour'
```

Or

```
BEFORE=$(( $(date '+%s') - 3600 )) ## In seconds = 1 hour.
find -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | while read -r TS FILE; do TS=${TS%.*}; [[ TS -ge BEFORE ]] && echo "$FILE"; done
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply,which shell does you use? what '-newerct'does do? I can`t find this option in doc

Comment: `-newerct` is the inode change time (like `-ctime`); not the creation time (like `-newerbt` or `-Btime`). OS X's `find` doesn't support `-printf`, but you can install GNU `find` with `brew install findutils`.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -depth 1 -Btime -1
```

and "-" to the num  defined